# i am trying to write a function which divide a column 3 parts

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to write a function which takes a column as input and divide it 3 parts as short, medium , long then return them as list.

i tried to do it with loc function, but, however, it return a dataframe rather than a list.

```
def DivideColumns(df,col):
    mean = df[col].mean()
    maxi  = df[col].max()
    mini  = df[col].min()
    less = mean - (maxi-mini)/3
    more = mean + (maxi-mini)/3
    short = df.loc[df[col] < less]
    average = df.loc[df[col].between(df[col], less, more)]
    long = df.loc[df[col] > more]
    return short, average, long;
```

what i am expected was getting 3 different list, but unfortunately i got 3 different dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using pandas you can use the concept of binning. By using the pandas `cut` function you can divide in the ranges you like and it makes your code easier to read. More info [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html)

```
def DivideColumns(df,col):
    mean = df[col].mean()
    maxi  = df[col].max()
    mini  = df[col].min()
    less = mean - (maxi-mini)/3
    more = mean + (maxi-mini)/3

    # binning
    bins_values = [mini, less, more, maxi]
    group_names = ['short', 'avarage', 'long']
    bins = pd.cut(df[col], bins_values, labels=group_names, include_lowest=True )


    short = (df[col][bins == 'short']).tolist()
    average = (df[col][bins == 'avarage']).tolist()
    long = (df[col][bins == 'long']).tolist()
    return short, average, long;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tolist()` function to transform a pandas `dataframe` into a list.

```py
short = df.loc[df[col] < less].values.tolist()
average = df.loc[df[col].between(df[col], less, more)].values.tolist()
long = df.loc[df[col] > more].values.tolist()
```

Comment: It does not work, i get error "Dataframe object has no attribute tolist"